# Grails : Implement Pagination without domain class

Tags: grails, pagination

I am new to Groovy Grails and want to implement pagination on list of image files.

In my code I don't have domain class, I am just fetching list of images from file system and displaying the images on gsp page.

Now I want to paginate the images that are being displayed.

Below is my gsp page on which the image files are being displayed.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ page import="filterList" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PC Screen Shots</title>
    <meta content="xenonPC" name="layout">
    <style>
    .mycontent-left {
        border-right: 1px solid #808080;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="col-md-12">

    <section class="gallery-env">
        <div class="">

            <div class="album-images row">

                <g:set var="selectedUser" value="${selectedUser}"/>
                <g:each in="${imageList}" var="imageName">
                    <!-- Album Image -->
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="album-image">
                            <a href="#" class="thumb" data-action="edit">
                                <img style="width: auto; height: 160px;"
                                     src="${createLink(controller: "customer", action: "displayImage", params: [imageName: imageName])}"
                                     class="img-responsive">
                            </a>

                            <div>
                                <g:set var="imageNameToDisplay" value="${imageName.toString()}"/>
                                <g:set var="imageNameToDisplay"
                                       value="${imageNameToDisplay.substring(imageNameToDisplay.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1)}"/>

                                <label>${imageNameToDisplay}</label>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <a href="#" class="thumb" data-action="edit">
                                    <img style="width: auto; height: 160px;"
                                         src="${createLink(controller: "customer", action: "displayImageDate", params: [imageName: imageName])}"
                                         class="img-responsive"
                                         style="cursor:pointer;">
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="image-options">

                                <g:link controller="customer" action="downloadImage" params="[imageName: imageName]">
                                    <i class="fa-download"></i>
                                </g:link>

                               <g:link controller="customer" action="deleteImage" params="[imageName: imageName, selectedUser: selectedUser]">
                                    <i class="fa-trash"></i>
                                </g:link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </g:each>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you will need a functionality that will split a given list to the specific chunk. pagination is reliant on sending as you are aware offset and max, with that same pagination value you can make your own custom method to work with a given list:

The actual method you need is this:

```
/**
 * paginate usage:
 * paginate(inputList,pagination-params)
 * paginationParams=[offset:params.offset,max:params.max]
 * instanceList=PaginationHelper.paginate(instanceList,paginationParams)
 * @param inputList
 * @param input
 * @return list split based on offset and max
 */
public static List splitList(List inputList, Map input) {
    input.max =  input.max ? (input.max as int) : 1
    input.offset =  input.offset ? (input.offset as int) : 0
    if (input.max < 0 ) return inputList

    def instanceTotal = inputList?.size()
    if ( input.offset < 0 ||  input.offset > instanceTotal) {
        input.offset = 0
    }
    // Ensure pagination does not exceed from array size
    Integer borderNumber =  input.max +  input.offset
    if (borderNumber > instanceTotal) {
        borderNumber = instanceTotal
    }
    // Extract sublist based on pagination
    def objectSubList = inputList.subList(input.offset, borderNumber)
    return objectSubList
}
```

To use this method:

```
    //your current list
    def myList=[['id':1L,name:'name'],['id':2L,name:'name']]

    //your page total for pagination within gsp
    def instanceListTotal=myList?.size() ?: 0 

    //set your pagination params as per pagination input by user
    def paginationParams = [offset: params.offset, max: params.max]

    // get the helper class above to split it 
    def instanceList= Helper.splitList(myList,paginationParams)

    //respond back with split result and actual total for pagination
    render (view:'view', model:[instanceList:instanceList,instanceListTotal:instanceListTotal])
```

so in effect use pagination with the above. Not recommended but hey sticky  situation requires unconventional solution.

The difference here and what typical pagination would be doing should be obvious but in the typical DB query model. There is no overall list like in this case `myList`. It is given starting point and max to return and goes off doing a fresh query. 
Pagination in a situation like this depends on list size and whilst it works it is having to load overall list over and over again each time pagination changes. 
You may wish to use some form of caching solution to maybe reduce the work here.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.